# How to cache Rails webpack packs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, webpack, webpacker

I have a Rails 6 app with a very large chunk of vendor CSS and JS. The CSS and JS will rarely ever change. I want Rails to cache it.

I have created 2 packs. 1 contains all the imports from vendor and the other contains imports of my app's JS. I use `javascript_packs_with_chunks_tag` in the head for both.

Whenever I modify my app's JS file, that pack's cache is invalidated along with the vendor's pack as well!

This behaviour seems to be normal as I was able to reproduce it with a new Rails app.

Edit: I can fix the problem in a new Rails app by turning off compiling (webpacker.yml `compile: false`) and running webpack in a separate terminal tab (`./bin/webpack --watch --colors --progress`), but in my app I still experience the problem. It seems like there is some global variable or keyword that Webpack is finding that connects the two packs. Unfortunately the Webpack logs and dependency graph doesn't reveal that "connection". It's 100% not an `import`.

Comment: The problem is that the output file hash for the vendor assets is changing even though the content is not changing. Apparently webpack adds timestamps and other stuff, so the hash is changing. If the output file name (incl. hash) doesn't change, caching will work. Webpack addresses this (webpack.js.org/guides/caching/), so it may be possible to appropriately configure webpack via webpacker.

Comment: Great tip, @LesNightingill !! Did you mean to say that "webpacker* adds timestamps and other stuff" ? Because according to webpack, "The [contenthash] substitution will add a unique hash based on the content of an asset. When the asset's content changes, [contenthash] will change as well.". But also, when you look at webpacker's config, https://gist.github.com/hrdwdmrbl/fb5c5b9e48186b6e9faecb374322cbd4#file-default_rails_webpack_config-json-L430, it looks like they don't explicitly add a timestamp or anything extra.

Comment: If you look a few paragraphs down from the quote you cited, it also says "If we run another build without making any changes, we'd expect that filename to stay the same. However, if we were to run it again, we may find that this is not the case" and then goes on to explain why. I think the timestamp etc is added inside the content, so the contenthash will change (that's what you're seeing, right?, the hash changes but you didn't make any changes to the vendor content). It looks as if webpacker will merge any options you provide. So see if you can incorporate the ideas that webpack documents.

Comment: do let us know if you succeed to get a contenthash that is based only on the code, and not the webpack overhead.

Comment: I just tried an experiment... run the webpack compile a couple of times on my dev machine, with no code changes... I'm not seeing the filename change, as the webpack docs suggest they might. So I might be completely wrong about this!! The question is... on your production server, does the vendor pack filename change when there's no code change? I'm not (yet) doing code splitting, so this might explain my result.

Comment: @LesNightingill I checked on my test rails app. It's an fresh clean app, just an application.js file and a vendor.js file). If I edit the application.js file, both files re-compile. However, only the filename (including hash) of the application.js file changes. BUT, even though the client still requests the same vendor.js filename, the server does not respond 304, it responds with 200 and sends the vendor.js file again. If I refresh the page without changing application.js, the server always responds 304.

Comment: the caching behaviour is different in dev and production environment. If the filename is not changing, it should be possible to configure the http headers in a way that achieves the desired result, e.g. https://mikerogers.io/2019/11/02/how-to-set-cache-control-headers-for-rails-webpacker-and-sprockets-assets.html

Comment: That is another good solution! That will probably prevent the browser from making a request each time, allowing caching by it. But that still means that the webserver is not behaving like I would expect. Do you think it could be because of the cache-groups? Perhaps when anything in the cache-group changes, the whole group is invalidated?

Comment: I played around with splitChunks and cacheGroups for a long time and it didn't work. There is something that webpacker does that causes caching to work differently. When I run rail's webpack along with the same configs the caching behaviour works better. I wish I understood this better.

Comment: @LesNightingill Those cache-control configs do work as another viable solution. If you add that answer before the bounty runs out I will award it to you for your help. 
But I do still feel like my question hasn't been answered because I still don't understand the details of how webpacker cache is (not) working and why it invalidates all packs when 1 pack is modified. What is that mechanism? Why does it behave that way? How can that behaviour be changed?

Comment: I found a documentation line that describes my situation "If you want to use live code reloading, or you have enough JavaScript that on-demand compilation is too slow," https://github.com/rails/webpacker#development

Unfortunately it doesn't explain how "on-demand compilation" relates to cache-invalidation

Answer (score 1):

One simple solution I found was to move the vendor CSS and JS to sprockets instead of webpack. I dislike this solution but it works.

To do this use the sprocket-type include statements

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'vendor' %>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'vendor' %>
```

and place your vendor js and CSS in their respective `app/assets` folders

Comment: And how do you do that?

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is to disable compiling
webpacker.yml
`compile: false`
and run webpack separately
$`./bin/webpack --watch --colors --progress`.

The is documented here https://github.com/rails/webpacker#development where it says "If [...] you have enough JavaScript that on-demand compilation is too slow...".

I dislike this solution as well because it doesn't explain why that is necessary. The problem is not that compilation is too slow but that caching isn't happening.  This solution usually does solve the caching problem at the same time though...

Answer (score 0):

Comments promoted here to an answer...

Whilst one would hope that compilation is skipped for the vendor code when that code doesn't change, this does not appear to be the case. However the filename of the compiled code *should not** change if the content doesn't change.

Assuming that you have achieved a filename that doesn't change, then the normal http cache control mechanisms should give the desired caching, even though the vendor code is being unnecessarily compiled. One reference for how to control http cache control headers is [here](https://mikerogers.io/2019/11/02/how-to-set-cache-control-headers-for-rails-webpacker-and-sprockets-assets.html)

*There is some ambiguity about this in the webpack docs, where it suggests that some versions may change the compiled filename (hash value), even with unchanged code, due to timestamps and other stuff added by webpack. The ([webpack docs](https://webpack.js.org/guides/caching)) do describe available mitigation measures if you find the filename hash to be changing.

Comment: It would be better not to link an external source without quoting or referencing or highlighting the important part (read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Can you describe briefly what is the fix/mitigation you suggest?